# powermta forwarding messages based on mx

Tags: sendgrid, powermta

i would like to forward messages based on their mx for a specific source / user
for example when a user is sending to xxx.com domain and xxx.com is hosted on office 365 based on mx servers i send it to a sendgrid.rollup and then push to sendgrid account

this config is working globally how can i localise it just for a specific virtual-pool/mta for a specific user?

`<mx-rollup-list> mx *.protection.outlook.com sendgrid.rollup rollup-by-ip </mx-rollup-list>`

`<domain sendgrid.rollup> max-smtp-out 5 max-msg-per-connection 50 max-errors-per-connection 10 max-msg-rate 10000/day use-unencrypted-plain-auth yes auth-username username auth-password password route smtp.sendgrid.net:587 use-starttls yes require-starttls yes </domain>`